# How can I dynamically define Object methods inside Ruby modules?

Tags: ruby

I have a case where I'm trying to leverage a database configuration file used by Padrino for a custom worker I'm writing without having to load the Padrino environment and without having to modify the existing database configuration. In short, I want to write my code to work with the existing database configuration code rather than modifying the existing configuration.

The database configuration file in question looks like the following:

```
# This is just here for right now so I can test
# to see if logger is set to anything in DB config
puts "Logger in DB config: #{logger}"

ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[:development] = {
  :adapter => 'sqlite3',
  :database => Padrino.root('db', "app_development.db") }
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = logger
ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = true
ActiveRecord::Base.store_full_sti_class = true
ActiveSupport.use_standard_json_time_format = true
ActiveSupport.escape_html_entities_in_json = false
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Padrino.env])
```

My custom worker looks like the following:

```
ROOT = File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(ROOT)

require 'active_record'
require 'logger'

# Mock Padrino module with methods used by database config file
module Padrino
  def self.root(*args)
    return File.expand_path(File.join("#{ROOT}/..", *args))
end

  def self.env
    return :development
  end
end

module Worker
  class << self
    attr_accessor :logger

    def init
      @logger       = Logger.new(STDOUT)
      @logger.level = Logger::DEBUG

      require "#{ROOT}/../config/database"
    end
  end
end

Worker.init
```

When I require the database configuration file in my worker I get an error saying the following:

```
/home/user/devel/app/config/database.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `logger' for main:Object (NameError)
from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
from worker.rb:26:in `init'
from worker.rb:31:in `<main>'
```

Given this, I modified the `Worker#init` function to be the following:

```
def init
  @logger       = Logger.new(STDOUT)
  @logger.level = Logger::DEBUG

  Object.send(:define_method, :logger, lambda { @logger })

  puts "Logger in Worker module: #{logger}"

  require "#{ROOT}/../config/database"
end
```

This change resulted in the following output:

```
Logger in Worker module: #<Logger:0x9505088>
Logger in DB config:
```

I take this to mean the `@logger` is not in scope in the database configuration file, even though I'm using a lambda when I define the logger method on Object.

Oddly enough, if I pull the `Object.send` line of code out of the `Worker#init` function and instead call it right before I call `Worker.init` like below, I get the following result.

```
Object.send(:define_method, :logger, lambda { Worker.logger })
Worker.init
```

results in

```
Logger in Worker module: #<Logger:0x81bc8b4>
Logger in DB config: #<Logger:0x81bc8b4>
```

Can someone explain to me why if I make the `Object.send` call inside the `Worker#init` function it doesn't work like it does if I make it outside the Worker module?

Comment: Please note that I figured out a way around my first question, which in turn led me to a new, but similar question, so I've edited my original post to reflect the new version of my original question. Hopefully this edit/rewrite was kosher with the StackOverflow rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example, you try to use undefined variable 'logger', as you can see from error message. Try to use the logger feature this way:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion WarHog, but in order to do what you've suggested I would have to modify the database config file generated and used by Padrino. Instead of doing that, I want to be able to use the config file by making my code work with it (trying to keep things DRY so I don't have to update my worker's database config file if I change the one for the Padrino app). I updated my original question to try and make this more clear.

Comment: Could you share your piece of code that work with config file?

Comment: WarHog, note that I figured out a way around my first question, which in turn led me to a new, but similar question, so I've edited my original post to reflect the new version of my original question.

Comment: Bryan, you're trying to use @logger variable in logger method. In case of calling inside your eigenclass of Worker module there is such variable, but when you leave that scope that variable stops its existence. Try make a call logger method right after 'Module.init' - you'll see that 'logger' method exists and returns nil. If you want to repair this situation with minimal effort, try to change Object.send line to '      Object.send(:define_method, :logger, lambda { Worker.logger })'

Comment: Thanks @WarHog, your last suggestion worked. Sorry for the late reply... I forgot to come back and post the results here. I've accepted your answer, but note that the answer that worked was in your comment above.